# Mouse cursor does not honor night light

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, cursor, redshift

I just installed 18.04.

Night Light is active, but the mouse cursor is not "red-shifting".
I am using the default 'DMZ-Black' cursor theme.

But the pointer outline is a glaring bright white color, the same as when Night Light is turned off.

Is there a way to get the mouse cursor to honor the Gnome Night Light setting?
(I do not want to install a different cursor theme).

Comment: I have had the same issue both on windows and linux. When doing my research to fix it on windows I came upon somebody saying that the pointer is being drawn by the gpu, which doesn't respect the night mode. I imagine this is as well the case for linux. The only solution they proposed was to use a different pointer sprite, but that would require you to change it manually daily. I have not found a good solution yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Do not compare two completely different OS :P . They both behave very differently and both have very different software to deal with their own problems. :) Most probably OP is referring to a "mutter" issue that has been lying around for a while. Mutter is one and only GNOME's window manager. Here is the bug report https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/5

Answer (score 2):

After spending 4+ hours I found the only solution:

- For now, it's not possible to change cursor color. Use custom cursors for night mode.

I didn't find good looking night cursors so tried to create myself. I used https://github.com/charakterziffer/cursor-toolbox and spent about 1h to change colors in `svgs/template.svg` to make ok looking cursors for day/night mode.

My example commit: https://github.com/fedotxxl/cursor-toolbox/commit/1ef4faa717fefb2d144871ad0fd4a060c6bf3877

Replace `style="fill:#000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#fff;stroke-opacity:1"` with your custom color, compile and try.

Hope it will help someone