# Night shift makes cursor overly red

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell

I've looked for someone else encountering this issue for quite a while now, but all I can find is the opposite, such as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033834/1709331).

When the GNOME night light feature is enabled, everything behaves as expected, except for the mouse cursor, which becomes far more orange than anything else. This is especially noticeable when against a white background:

[image of the cursor against a white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm64R.jpg)

Weirdly, I've had to take a real picture of my screen to show this, as if I try to take a screenshot with the cursor included, its colours become normal (i.e. the same warm colour of white as everything else).

If it is off, white colours on the cursor look the same as white colours elsewhere.

This is very off-putting, as it makes the mouse cursor very inconsistent with the rest of the screen.